# Aggregate in MongoDB in arrays with specific records

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregate

My database looks like:

```
{email:"user", contacts: 
 [
  {emailContact:"test", firstName:"test", lastName:"test", messages:
   [
    {email:"user", content:"hi", date:"ISODate(...)"}
    {email:"test", content:"how are you?", date:"ISODate(...)"}
    {email:"user", content:"im fine", date:"ISODate(...)"}
   ]
  },
  {emailContact:test2, firstName:"test2", lastName:"test2", messages:
   [
    {email:"user", content:"hahaha", date:"ISODate(...)"}
    {email:"test2", content:"yea thats right", date:"ISODate(...)"}
    {email:"user", content:"xd", date:"ISODate(...)"}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I need to get 2 last messages from the specific user with a given contact.

I've tried already several similar:

```
db.contacts.aggregate([{$match:{email:"user",emailContact:"test"}},{$unwind:{'contacts.messages'}},{$sort:{'contacts.messages.date':1,'contacts.messages.content':1,'contacts.messages.emailContact':1}},{$group:{who:'$email', content:'$content', date:{$last:'$date'}}}])
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: can you provide some actual documents so we can give you working query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double `$unwind` could do it.

```
db.contacts.aggregate([
  {$match: {email: 'user'}},
  {$unwind: '$contacts'},
  {$match: {'contacts.emailContact': 'test'}},
  {$unwind: '$contacts.messages'},
  {$sort: {'contacts.messages.date': -1}},
  {$limit: 2},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$contacts.messages'}}
])
```